# Launch modal after submitting the form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How to launch a modal at the time a form is submitted and that has passed through the validation of ModelState.IsValid. The modal content is just a text warning "wait" for the end of the process the page will be redirected.

Comment: Are you doing a standard submit (or posted the form values via ajax)?

Comment: The traditional method without ajax @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then you cant. As soon as you click the submit button, you have left the page. You could however handle the `.submit()` event, cancel it, display the message and wait for a period then do the actual submit.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It turns out that this form performs a number of tasks such as uploading files, file changes and other tasks. And take a while, would like to display a message to the user wait. At the moment the process end, the page is redirected. This process takes approximately 10 to 20 seconds.